# Build failure while building a project using ElasticSearch-Hadoop

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-hadoop

I am unable to build a Java project which uses `ElasticSearch-Hadoop`.
This is the error that I am seeing, when I try to build my project:

```
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building testES 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
The POM for cascading:cascading-local:jar:2.5.5 is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for cascading:cascading-hadoop:jar:2.5.5 is missing, no dependency information available
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 6.499s
Finished at: Mon Sep 08 11:29:08 IST 2014
Final Memory: 8M/19M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal on project testES: Could not resolve dependencies for 
project org.edge:testES:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not 
be resolved: cascading:cascading-local:jar:2.5.5, cascading:cascading-
hadoop:jar:2.5.5: Failure to find cascading:cascading-local:jar:2.5.5 in 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has 
elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read  
the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Below are the dependencies in the POM file for the project:-

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I had the same issue last week. It seems like the repo is missing from the site.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are blocking maven to look at [spring-source](http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release-remote/cascading/cascading-hadoop/2.5.2/) repository, to make it work add following snippet in your `pom.xml`

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>

    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/</url>
    </repository>

  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but now it is not able to find the other artifacts (namely junit,elasticsearch-hadoop,hadoop-core) which are avaiable on Maven repository. below is the error I get even after adding the following to pom.xml file:-                      <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/</url>
    </repository>
    
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

Comment: Failed to execute goal on project testES: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.edge:testES:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 (test), org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:jar:2.1.0.Beta1 (compile), org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:1.2.1 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for cascading:cascading-local:jar:2.5.5: Could not transfer artifact cascading:cascading-local:pom:2.5.5 from/to spring-milestones (http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]